# model.fetch({success: function() }); taking long time to get the server response and getting delayed to load

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, model, marionette, fetch

I'm writing a model.fetch success function and it is taking much time to get the JSON response and it is delayed in loading. When debugging every time it was looping until success and again after in the next iteration it was looping inside that function

My code is as follow:

```
    functionOne: function (evt) {
        if (this.model.get('Code') !== Code) {
            // need to handle the selected type
            this.model.set('Code', Id);
            this.model.fetch({
                success: function () {
                    this.functionTwo();
                }
            });
        }
    },
    functionTwo: function () {

        this.ui.List.trigger('change');

        // if required reset single list also

        this.initialize(this.options);
        this.Method();
    }
```

Comment: Was `functionTwo` ever called ? Because in the success callback of model fetch, `this` would not be pointing to the reference you expect it to point.

Comment: I agree with Cyclone, this.functionTwo() wont be the scope you expect.